# Closure-Reopening-Reclosure: Analyzing the final cadence of Dvorak 9 Finale

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Analyzing the final cadence of Dvorak 9 Finale](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9875/analyzing-the-final-cadence-of-dvorak-9-finale) was closed, then reopened, and then re-closed.  What is going on to my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You closed it as a duplicate. The question wasn't a duplicate of that question at all so it was reopened, but it was off topic so it was closed as that reason.

From my comment on that question when it happened:

> Analysis questions are off topic here. Also it makes no sense that  you closed your own question as a duplicate of a completely different question you asked.

---

As an update this question is now deleted. It was bumped via edit to the answer again today and with no change in the off-topic nature of the question itself. Since it was clearly off-topic and there's no attempts to fix or reopen it, having it bump back on the main page does not make sense so the deletion prevents this from happening again.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya And this is the straw that broke the camel's back. Nothing in the question you posted, the answer you gave to that question, and the comment above makes sense on the Music Fan's site. This is not Music SE and you cannot treat it like a secondary Music SE.